# User Channels / Unknown Subresource

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-php

The newly added (05/02) User Channels resource seems to be dead. When I attempt to access this data I always receive an error that says "Unknown subresource channels".

Can anyone confirm that this functionality is actually working?

I've tried retrieving it a couple of different ways:

```
$channels = $this->client->chat
  ->services($this->ipmSid)
  ->users($memberId)
  ->channels
  ->read(); // I've also tried ->fetch();
```

and then I tried using the link that is provided when you fetch a member and feeding that directly into curl like this:

```
$member = $this->client->chat
  ->services($this->ipmSid)
  ->users($user_id)
  ->fetch();

$url = $member->links['user_channels'];
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $this->sid . ":" . $this->token);
$resp = curl_exec($ch);
```

Both ways result in a 500 error "Twilio Exception Unknown Subresource Channels".

Thanks for any tips!

Comment: Hey, a 500 response means we're doing something wrong! I would raise this with [Twilio support](https://www.twilio.com/help/contact) and that should get it looked at quicker.

Comment: Thanks philnash, I did open a support ticket as you suggested prior to posting here. I actually received a response pretty quickly requesting further information but I figured I'd get some insight from the community in the meantime to ensure I wasn't missing something silly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not documented well. You need to use userChannels.

```
channels = $this->client->chat
    ->services($this->ipmSid)
    ->users($memberId)
    ->userChannels
    ->read();
```